# Custom [] access for mulltiset in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, multiset

I was writing a basic piece of code using multiset. And ran into a problem. I am fairly new to STL and couldn't find anything particularly relevant to help me with custom access for multiset elements.

```
// Custom class - 3 integers and a Compare function
class Sums 
{
    public:
        Sums(int v1, int v2, int v3) : val1(v1), val2(v2), val3(v3) {};
        bool operator<(const Sums &v) const { return val3 < v.val3; }

        int val1;
        int val2;
        int val3;
};

// Multiset using the above class, sorted using val3
multiset<Sums> b;
b.insert(Sums(1, 2, 11));
b.insert(Sums(0, 1, 20));

// This works.
auto i = b.find(Sums(1,2,11));
cout << i->val1 << ' ' << i->val2 << ' ' << i->val3 << endl;

/* But, suppose I only know that the element of the multiset which I have to find has val1=1 and val2=2, and I don't know the corresponding value of val3.
Is it possible to somehow overload the [] operator, so that the following works? Because, I can't use find() without knowing the values of all three data members of the class.*/

cout << b[1].val3 << endl;  // I want this to print 11.
cout << b[1][2].val3 << endl; // Is this also possible?
```

Comment: What should happen when there are multiple values satisfying those search conditions? Since your container is not sorted with respect to `val1,val2` the best you can do is to use `std::find_if`, which is O(n).

Comment: If you want to find element by `val3` without knowing the rest of values you can use `std::find_if` like Quimby said or for faster search you can create a `std::map`/`std::multimap` where object of `Sums` are values and `val3`s are keys.

Comment: In the application, there won't be multiple values. Because val1 and val2 correspond to indices of another different array. And val3 corresponds to the sum of the contents of the array at those two indices. So, I guess there won't be multiple values. And, I wanted to know also, if I could possibly do better than O(n) somehow ?

Comment: So, multimap is a way out. Right. But, is there any way with only a multiset? If there isn't, I will have to do multimap then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
#include <algorithm>

// Your struct / classes here

void foo() {
    multiset<Sums> b;
    b.insert(Sums(1, 2, 11));
    b.insert(Sums(0, 1, 20));

    auto i = std::find_if(b.cbegin(), b.cend(), [](const Sums &v) -> bool { 
    return v.val1 == 1 && v.val2 == 2; });
```

}

This algorithm is O(n) and you can't do better, at least with a multiset.